# recontar campos de woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy  ejecutando un script propio que me sube de un archivo csv una lista de productos a mi woocommerce , borra todos los productos y inserta los del documento ,todo se ejecutar bien pero tengo que acceder a woocoomer/estado/herramientas/Recuentos de términos para que todo quede perfecto.
Alguna idea de como automatizar este recuento de términos periódicamente?

Comment: Encontre algo de codigo que no se si me podria ser util en mi script.Lo adjunto:    
                                                                                           
             wp_update_term_count ( int | array  $ terms , string  $ taxonomy , bool  $ do_deferred  =  false  )

Comment: proba con [`wc_recount_after_stock_change( $product_id )`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_recount_after_stock_change.html)

Comment: Como la puedo llamar desde mi php?no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- descarga e instala el [`WP-cli`](https://wp-cli.org/)
- en la carpeta donde tenes el script que va a updatear ( por ejemplo `~/wp-scripts/` ) configura el wp-cli para que encuentre la instalación del wordpress, es decir la carpeta donde está el `wp-config.php` por ejemplo si está en `/var/www/html`:

`~/wp-scripts/wp-cli.yml`

```
path: /var/www/html
apache_modules:
  - mod_rewrite
```

- script que busca todos los productos y les recuenta los terms

`~/wp-scripts/wc_products_update_terms.php`

```
<?php
// https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query
// Get all products. Return IDs
$args = array(
  'limit' => -1,
  'return' => 'ids',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

// https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_recount_after_stock_change.html
foreach( $products as $product_id ){
  echo "Product ID:{$product_id}";
  wc_recount_after_stock_change( $product_id );
  echo " updated" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

- ejecuta el script por medio del wp-cli:

`~/wp-scripts/$ wp eval-file wc_products_update_terms.php`

resultado:

```
Product ID:4479 updated
Product ID:3307 updated
Product ID:3293 updated
Product ID:3292 updated
Product ID:2942 updated
```

**Edit**

En caso de querer ponerlo en un cron y/o no depender de un archivo de configuración, se usa el argumento `--path=` para indicar la carpeta donde está wordpress.

Un ejemplo de crontab asumiendo que el wp cli está instalado global en `/usr/local/bin/` :

```
12 6 * * * /usr/local/bin/wp eval-file /home/usuario/wp-scripts/wc_products_update_terms.php --path=/var/www/html
```

Hay mas opciones para [configurar wp-cli](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/) una de las mas útiles al ejecutar scripts puntuales es `--skip-plugins=` donde le das una lista separada por comas de los plugins que no necesitas o no deseas que estén activos al momento de ejecutarse el script.

Un ejemplo práctico pueden ser plugins de redirección o que filtran el contenido según el usuario: `--skip-plugins=redirection,coming-soon-page`.

Experimentando un poco con qué plugins excluir ( recordar hacer backup o trabajar sobre una copia del site ) podes mejorar el rendimiento del script, algo que es complicado de lograr con la técnica de hacer un `require_once` del `wp-load.php`, con el agregado de que si no hay functions, custom post types o taxonomies definidas en el theme podes excluirlo también con `--skip-themes`.

**Edit 2**

Woocommerce extiende `wp-cli` con comandos y herramientas de la forma `wp wc ...`, revisando la [documentación](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Overview#command) veo que ya hay una herramienta que realiza esta tarea:

```
$ wp wc tool run recount_terms --user=1
```

Comment: Es posible hacer lo mismo pero utilizando un cron en lugar de el wpCli para ejecutarlo cada x tiempo?Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: agregado un ejemplo de cron, `wp eval-file` ejecuta el script como si estuviera en un `functions.php`, mas info en https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/